# Running a graph by object orientated programming through python

Tags: python, object, input, graph

My question is about input into an object with python.

I am trying to make an object whereby I open this python file, it asks me to input a data file's path, I input the path and it will print a graph out for me of that data.

So far I have this:

```
def graph_openprices():
while True:
    try:
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        from matplotlib import style
        import numpy as np
        path_openprices = input("Input file path_g: ")

        style.use('ggplot')

        x,y = np.loadtxt(path_openprices, unpack = True, delimiter= ',')
        plt.plot(x,y)

        plt.title('My chart')
        plt.ylabel('Y axis')
        plt.xlabel('X axis')

        plt.show()

        anykey = input("Input anything to return to the main menu ")
        exit

    except OSError:
        print("Directory incorrect, please input a valid directory")
        graph_openprices()

graph_openprices()
```

I am running this code, however, every time it asks me to input my code and I input it

```
D:\Mycode\exampleFile.txt
```

Nothing happens, nothing comes up and it is just space. However, when I deactivate the path_openprices line by putting a # in front, and type the path where path_openprices is in the x,y variable, it works.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can make the input part work please?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `input` which tries to evaluate the given input as Python code -- see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) which tells you it's equivalent to running `eval(raw_input(...))`.

```
$ echo 'D:\MyCode\lol.txt' | python -c 'input()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    D:\MyCode\lol.txt
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You typically don't want to evaluate arbitrary strings given by the user, so use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use `try` with only a specific matching exception, in a `while True` loop, so if some other error happens, you will not be told what it was.

Use `print` statements to see what the code is doing when it seems it's doing nothing.